# are RTLD_LOCAL and RTLD_DEEPBIND recursive?

Tags: linux, dlopen

The DLOPEN man page docuements two flags which can be used to workaround symbol conflicts between shared libraries. RTLD_LOCAL which means symbols from the library are not loaded into the global symbol namespace and RTLD_DEEPBIND which prefers local symbols over global ones.

Do these flags only apply to the library that is directly loaded or do they also apply to the dependencies that are loaded as part of loading that library?